Where did the information required for the trials in Agatha All Along come from?
In the Disney+ TV series Agatha All Along what was the motivation behind the trial of the different witches?
As we know that

 Billy Maximoff was the one who created the witches road and he created the different trials for the witches. As we know that he did not know much about the witches from before how was he able to create trials that were personal to all the witches? Where did he get the motivation to create such detailed trials with costumes and themes?

How are the trials in so much detail and what is their inspiration?

Mostly the stuff in his bedroom.

Billy's powers created the Road (much like his mother's powers created the sitcom reality of her town), based on his interests and expectations, and on what he heard the others say and read from their minds. There's no particular motivation for the trials other than Billy's belief that trials are supposed to happen, and his powers making things happen the way he thinks they are supposed to happen.
When the coven first entered the Road, Billy says:

It's exactly how I pictured it.

No surprise since he was creating it. And the Road's features match items in Billy's room - again because his subconscious mind is creating it.
Trials are mentioned in the Ballad

Through many miles of tricks and trials
We'll wander high and low
Tame your fears, a door appears
The time has come to go

Note that the first trial manifests facial distortion immediately after Sharon says:

Well, I'm not saying that I wanna join the club or anything, but I
would drink the blood of a virgin if it would smooth out some of these
wrinkles.

Everything that happens during the later trials can be explained in this fashion - trials were fashioned to suit the witches because he can read their minds.
And as @paul-d-waite  notes, Billy had some knowledge of the other witches from his initial meetings with them - enough to learn that Alice was haunted by the death of her mother, etc.

Got the answer, I was missing a major point that he can read their minds.

It might be worth noting that he did have some foreknowledge of the other witches in the coven. He had engaged with Jen’s social media content, and was a fan of Alice’s mum’s band (or at least their version of the ballard). He also encountered them all with Agatha during the recruitment drive, during which Agatha was using her centuries of scamming experience to get a rapid read on each witch’s psychology, to work out how to persuade them to join their temporary coven.
